# how to check if particular file exists in s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and I want to check if a particular csv exists in a folder in s3 . And if it does i want to read it and if it doesn't i want to create a df and upload it to s3.

what i did till now

```
list_of_files = []
    for key in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket= 'abc',Prefix="folder/")['Contents']:
        list_of_files.append(key['Key'])
```

```
check_files = [list of file to check]
```

something like

```
if set(check_files) in set(list_of_files):
   read_from_s3(file)
else:
  pd.Dataframe()
```

Comment: You can use `head_object()`, but why make two calls when one will suffice? Just try to download it / read it and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 6):

Use the s3_client get_object.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object

If the object doesn't exists it will throw exception
S3.Client.exceptions.NoSuchKey

Check below sample

```
        try:
            s3_client.get_object(
                Bucket=self._bucket,
                Key=key,
            )
            return True
        except s3_client.exceptions.NoSuchKey:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than boto3 client you can use s3fs package.
Install:

```
pip install s3fs
```

```
#Code
from s3fs.core import S3FileSystem
fs= S3FileSystem()
exists = fs.exists(S3_URI)
print(exists)
```

S3_URI looks something like this: "s3://your_bucket_name/folder/test.csv"

And to Read or write csv file to s3, you use aws wrangler.

```
pip install awswrangler
```

```
import awswrangler as wr

# AWS S3 configuration
s3_bucket_name = 'your-s3-bucket-name'
s3_object_key = 'path/to/your/csv-file.csv'
aws_access_key_id = 'your-access-key-id'
aws_secret_access_key = 'your-secret-access-key'
aws_region = 'your-aws-region'

# Read the CSV file from S3
df = wr.s3.read_csv(
    path=f's3://{s3_bucket_name}/{s3_object_key}',
    boto3_session=wr.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key, region_name=aws_region),
)

# Now you can work with the DataFrame 'df' as needed
print(df.head())
```