# Check if file exists in s3 and read if its present

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS. I want to read multiple files on a daily basis and need to perform fewer actions on them. The problem is if the file is not created today ill face an error. Since I need to automate this process I need to read a file if only it existed. Else pass and don't throw errors.

Ex = file name - abc2022-10-01
abc2022-10-03

read_from_s3 (file) only if exists
else go to the next operation

Comment: "face an error. " - what error? What is your actual python code producing the error?

Comment: That file doesn't exists. And i want the code to continue if the file is not there by ignoring the file which is not present.

Comment: You should simply attempt to read the file. Then, if an error is returned, your program should handle that error by exiting the program. What have you tried and what _specific_ problem are you facing?

Comment: I have multiple files if one doesn't read i don't want the program to exit. Rather i want it to continue ignoring the error file

Comment: You already asked this yesterday and got correct answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check if particular file exists in s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537146/how-to-check-if-particular-file-exists-in-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to know if the key is preset in S3.
You can use list_objects_v2 [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)! The Method will return list of keys over which you can iterate.