# How to directly generate presigned url if key exist in S3, or upload obj and create key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to check if a object with a specific key exist in S3, and if so I want to directly generate a presigned url, and if not, I will upload the object to S3 and then generate the presigned url. I found some solutions to check if key exist such as [how to check if particular file exists in s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537146/how-to-check-if-particular-file-exists-in-s3-bucket), but this costs one more round trip. I wonder if there is a better way to implement this. Will `generate_presigned_url` throw a specific exception if the key does not exist?

I want something like the following, and also I want to catch all other types of exception and log it.

```
# Generating a pre-signed URL
try:
    presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                        Params={'Bucket': s3_bucket,
                                                                'Key': image_key},
                                                        ExpiresIn=100) 
                                                        
except "key does not exist":
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(image_byte, s3_bucket, image_key, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'image/png'})
    presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                        Params={'Bucket': s3_bucket,
                                                                'Key': image_key},
                                                        ExpiresIn=100) 

except "all other exceptions":
        print(e)
        logging.error(e)
        return "Error"
```

Comment: Generating a presigned URL does not actually communicate with S3 at all, so there's no exception to be thrown if the key doesn't exist.  If you want to check for the key, you need to [explicitly check with S3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376288)